# Merge arrays by same key and value PHP

Tags: php

How to merge 2 arrays replacing elements with the same key=>value ('day' in my case) pair.

**Expected Input:**

```
$array1 = Array
(
    Array
    (
        'day' => '2019-10-19',
        'uniques' => 0,
    ),
    Array
    (
        'day' => '2019-10-20',
        'uniques' => 0,
    ),
    Array
    (
        'day' => '2019-10-21',
        'uniques' => 0,
    )
);

$array2 = Array
(
    Array
    (
        'day' => '2019-10-19',
        'uniques' => 15,
    ),
    Array
    (
        'day' => '2019-10-21',
        'uniques' => 10,
    )
);
```

The output array should contain all array1 elements replaced with array2 values where the 'day' value is the same.

**Expected Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2019-10-19
            [uniques] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2019-10-20
            [uniques] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2019-10-21
            [uniques] => 10
        )
)
```

I tried array_replace_recursive() but it doesn't work.

Comment: You will need two nested loops (effectively, of course this stuff can be rewritten using array functions most of the time); or you modify your second array first, so that it uses the date as key (so that you can then use it for directly look-ups, explicitly “searching” through the elements of the second array each time would not be necessary then.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to turn the first array into an indexed array (by date using `array_column()`) and then loop over the second and update each value as you go.  Then remove the keys using `array_values()` at the end...

```
$a1 = array_column($array1, null, 'day');
foreach ( $array2 as $day ) {
    $a1[$day['day']] = $day;
}

print_r(array_values($a1));
```

Answer (score 0):

complete solution is here

```
    $array1 = Array
    (
         Array
               (
                 'day' => '2019-10-19',
                 'uniques' => 0,
               ),
               Array
              (
                'day' => '2019-10-20',
                'uniques' => 0,
              ),
               Array
              (
               'day' => '2019-10-21',
              'uniques' => 0,
             )
      );

    $array2 = Array
   (
      Array
      (
       'day' => '2019-10-19',
       'uniques' => 15,
     ),
     Array
     (
       'day' => '2019-10-21',
       'uniques' => 10,
      )
   );

  function uniqueAssocArray($array, $uniqueKey) {
  if (!is_array($array)) {
  return array();
   }
   $uniqueKeys = array();
   foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    if (!in_array($item[$uniqueKey], $uniqueKeys)) {
     $uniqueKeys[$item[$uniqueKey]] = $item;
     }
   }
    return $uniqueKeys;
  }

    $rr=array_merge($array1,$array2);
   $resultArray = uniqueAssocArray($rr, 'day');
   print_r($resultArray);
```